# pick or choose with accumulator

Tags: function, collections, language-agnostic, f#

I am looking for a function like f#'s pick or choose but that threads an accumulator in.

`List.choose : ('T -> 'U option) -> 'T list -> 'U list`

`List.pick : ('T -> 'U option) -> 'T list -> 'U`

I want this :

`List._choose : ('T -> 'State -> ('U option, 'State)) -> 'State -> 'T list -> 'U list`

`List._pick : ('T -> 'State -> ('U option, 'State)) -> 'State -> 'T list -> 'U`

Where 'State would be the accumulator.

The answer I am looking for is the name of such a function, and the language and/or library the function lives in.

Comment: I don't get it - since the state doesn't appear in an output position it seems like it doesn't need to be passed in at all (it can just be implicitly closed over given the existing `List.choose` signature)...  Could you give an example of the usage you imagine?

Comment: How does the state change? Is it assumed to be `ref`?

Comment: Good point, I have made the "chooser" function return a tuple.

Comment: How is this different from a fold?

Comment: A fold does not short circuit

Comment: Here is a quick usage example: Turn this string of numbers in sequential order into an array of numbers that are in sequential order. The 'State would be the number of digits that I need to pull next. `9899100101102103104105`

Comment: You could just put the state as a ref cell outside the choose.

Comment: yes, but I am looking for a solution without side effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be close to a well-known [mapreduce](/questions/tagged/mapreduce) problem, and I think, it should be solved in a similar manner, **by separating *Map*, *Group*, and *Reduce* steps**.

Let's take the problem of converting a `string` to a list of ordered `int`'s, as you suggested.

```
let stringToInts (xs:string) =
    /// The Mapper simply maps the character to its numeric value
    let mapper = string >> Int32.Parse

    /// The Grouper "concatenates" 'x' to the 'current' value
    /// if the result is greater than the 'threshold', updates the
    /// 'threshold' and drops the 'current'
    /// otherwise, just updates the 'current'
    let grouper (threshold, current) x =
        let newCurrent = current*10 + x
        if newCurrent > threshold
            then newCurrent, 0
            else threshold, newCurrent

    /// The Reducer takes only the values with zero 'current' field
    /// and unwraps the tuple
    let reducer = function
        | x, 0 -> Some x
        | _    -> None

    xs.ToCharArray()              // get the chars
    |> List.ofArray               // convert to List
    |> List.map mapper            // **Map them to int values
    |> List.scan grouper (97, 0)  // **Group the values so that each one
                                  // is greater than the threshold
    |> List.choose reducer        // **Reduce by zero 'current'
    |> List.tail                  // skip the bootstrapper

"9899100101102103104105"
|> stringToInts
|> List.iter (printf "%O ")
// outputs:
// 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105
```

One may wrap all three steps into a single function, but I really see no practical reason doing it.

Comment: I agree. But if I was to create a reusable function like I wanted, what do you think the name of it should be? I'm thinking about creating a push request.